# On iPhone: Find out what song is currently playing? (in the iPod music player)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod

Apple released [access to the iPod Library](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) in the iPhone SDK 3.0 and I'm wondering if it's now possible to understand which song is currently playing? Title, Artist, Album suffices. Example: User opens an app and the app can know which song is playing in the background.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This has already been answered here on SO: [iPhone sdk - accessing current song information through an app.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741847/iphone-sdk-accessing-current-song-information-through-an-app)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
MPMediaItem * song = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
NSString * title   = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSString * album   = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
NSString * artist  = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
```

Comment: Note: You'll need to include MediaPlayer.framework first.