# Getting the current song playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On iPhone: Find out what song is currently playing? (in the iPod music player)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917014/on-iphone-find-out-what-song-is-currently-playing-in-the-ipod-music-player)

Is it possible to get info ob the currently playing song in the iPhone's music player?
Can it b accessed from a different app?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class.

> ```
> + (MPMusicPlayerController *)iPodMusicPlayer
> Return Value
>
> The iPod music player.
> nowPlayingItem
>
> The currently-playing media item, or the media item, within a queue, that you have designated to begin playback with.
> @property (nonatomic, copy) MPMediaItem *nowPlayingItem
> ```

```
MPMediaItem *currentPlayingSong = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm unfamilliar with the MPMediaItem and not near a mac now, can I get the ID3 details? like artist and name etc?