# Get the name of a track the user is playing in iOS

Tags: ios, ipod

As part of an iOS application we are trying to make, we would like a very small part of our application to keep running is the background, and save the names of the tracks the iPod is playing, and/or send them to our server.

So basically we want to register an event listener that tells our app when the iPod application plays a track, even if our app is in the background.

Is this possible? I have been digging around in the documentation and haven't found much useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current playing song and just add them to an array of string by getting the names
[On iPhone: Find out what song is currently playing? (in the iPod music player)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917014/on-iphone-find-out-what-song-is-currently-playing-in-the-ipod-music-player)

EDIT: Better answer in this link

EDIT 2:

There's this link
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45438-different-sound-volumes-mpmusicplayer-system-sounds.html

A bit down he talks about some methods which gets invoked on song changes

```
- (void)handleNowPlayingItemChanged:(id)notification {
    MPMediaItem *currentItem = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
    self.songLabel.text   = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    self.artistLabel.text = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This solves the retrieving the name of the track. But since we want to do this from the background, is there a way to register an event listener that gets notified when the iPod plays a song?