# How to choose next song in remoteControlledEvents

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` where I can control play, pause function by double tapping home button or in technical terms `remoteControlledEvents`. I was wondering how to implement it so I can go to the next track in `remoteControlledEvents`.

Thanks

```
-(void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  switch (event.subtype) {
    case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
      if (avplayer.rate == 0.0) {
        [avplayer play];
      } else {
        [avplayer pause];
      }
      break;
    case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
      [avplayer play];
      break;
    case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
      [avplayer pause];
      break;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a new `AVPlayer` with the next song and tell it to play.

The event is `UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack`

```
case: UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
    [avplayer pause];
    avplayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:/*name of item*/];
    [avplayer play];
    break;
```

Comment: what should go in initWithPlayerItem

Comment: Whatever the next track you want to play is.

Comment: The songs will be fetched from the iPod Library

Comment: However you're starting the playback (the first song) do the same thing for the second song. You haven't posted enough of your code for me to tell you exactly what code you need to use, but it shouldn't be too difficult since I'm assuming you already have the setup in place.

Comment: Is `avplayer` not leaking here since you are allocing over top of it?

Comment: After you overwrite the reference to it ARC should deallocate it